# Revalidate row of DataGrid after source/binding has been updated

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

It seems to me, that `DataGrid` only applies a `ValidationRule` defined as row validation rules inside

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
...
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

if the user makes an input. My view model implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and because of some asynchrounus background action the value of a cell might get invalid. Validation on cell level works perfectly with `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors = true` and my custom validation styles. However, my row validation rule that checks the cells for potentially invalid data will only update (and then mark the row invalid) if I manually make an arbitrary input (i.e. I start editing a cell and press Enter). Is there a possibility to manually trigger the row validation for a single/specific row? Is this behavior the intended behavior? Isn't the data grid supposed to revalidate in case a cell gets invalid?

---

This really drives me insance. I tried the same approach with `IDataErrorInfo` to verify that `DataGrid` has no bug. Below is a very simple WPF application. One can verify that the row validation will only trigger when the user changes the highlighted cell. Is there no way to trigger a row validation on my own? The only "solution" would to reduce validation on the cell level. For that purpose I created a dummy/read-only object property that aggregates all errors of the row. I use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and return all errors if `GetErrors` is called with the dummy properties name. However, this can't be the solution! The whole WPF builds around Validation. `VisualStateManager` relies on internal validation, ...

**Person.cs**

```
class Person : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = null;
            switch(columnName)
            {
                case nameof(Name):
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                    {

                        error = "Name is empty";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return error;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if(propertyName != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        } else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonsViewModel.cs**

```
class PersonsViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _personsList;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsList
    {
        get { return _personsList ?? (_personsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>()); }
    }

    public PersonsViewModel()
    {
        PersonsList.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Bob"
        });
        PersonsList.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Alice"
        });
        PersonsList.Add(new Person()
        {
            Name = "Max"
        });
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTesting"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                    <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="CommittedValue"/>
                </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button x:Name="MakeInvalidButton" Click="MakeInvalidButton_Click" Content="Make me invalid"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PersonsViewModel viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new PersonsViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void MakeInvalidButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var alice = viewModel.PersonsList.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Alice")).First();
        if (alice != null)
        {
            alice.Name = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want DataErrorValidationRule which checks for errors raised by the IDataErrorInfo interface on the source object.  This is directly analogous to the ValidationOnNotifyDataErrors for cells.  However this implies that the data is validated in the source object.

Comment: Doesn't INotifyDataErrorInfo do the same but in a more modern way? Is this maybe a bug? Do you have working example that uses IDataErrorInfo?

Comment: The classic implementation of IDataErrorInfo is DataRowView which is part of the View Model for the DataSet.  So a lot depends on what you think of the DataSet as to what is newer, more modern or a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mix VB.NET and C#.

Comment: Did you implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface and raised the ErrorsChanged event each time you want to trigger a row validation?

Comment: I do. Like in the example above. And I know that I trigger the error event right because validation on cell level works (my cell error template immediately shows).

Comment: My problem is a more general one: Do I dump the whole validation system for the `DataGrid` and build my controls around my specific view models or do I build around the validation system allowing my to use `VisualStateManager`, `ValidationRules` and so on. The latter one is the more general approach and also more flexibel approach. And I'm also sure that it's the better one.

Comment: Well generally you do not use validation in the datagrid to validate the data source. The purpose of validation rules is to validate data entry.  The data source (i.e. the model) must have its own validation.  Why?  Because the model must be valid even if no one is viewing the data.  So the right way to do things is to move the validation to path along which data is changing in the model.